# Observerable appending data over and over again on populate action

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a Mat-Table that is duplicating the data when the user clicks the button to populate the table.

Now the API is correct and I have other tables that work just fine.

The only caveat with this table is that this table has a clickable detail rows.

So the goal here is to return 2 rows for every incoming row. Row 1 to populate the table and row 2 as the detail row for when the user clicks a table row.  (The first time the user clicks populate everything is fine)

What I see happening is this: The data from the API returns 5 rows. (which is correct) and the datasource from the connect method should then return an array of 10 back.

However if I click the populate button again the table will display 20 rows, then 30 then 40 on subsequent clicks.

I thought maybe the rows array wasn't getting reset but I've set the length to 0 and still have the issue.

I believe that the issue is in this method.

```
connect(collectionViewer: CollectionViewer): Observable<Gizmos[]> {
    this.rows.length = 0;

    return this.Gizmosubject.asObservable()
      .pipe(
      map(x => {
        //alert("Length going in: " + x.length);   -- I always have the correct count 
        x.forEach(gizmo =>
          this.rows.push(gizmo, { detailRow: true, gizmo }));
          //alert("Rows: " + this.rows.length);    -- I notice here where rows keeps growing. (As the user clicks the action)
        console.log(this.rows);
          return this.rows;
        })
      );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want for every 5 records to return array of 10 records (and not the cumulative result) you should not always push in `this.rows`, or you can reset `this.rows` before populating it. Try something like this:

```
connect(collectionViewer: CollectionViewer): Observable<Gizmos[]> {

 return this.Gizmosubject.asObservable()
  .pipe(
  map(x => {
    //alert("Length going in: " + x.length);   -- I always have the correct count 
    this.rows = [];   // <== Notice this line which will reset rows
    x.forEach(gizmo =>
      this.rows.push(gizmo, { detailRow: true, gizmo }));
      //alert("Rows: " + this.rows.length);    -- I notice here where rows keeps growing. (As the user clicks the action)
    console.log(this.rows);
      return this.rows;
    })
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you reset it when the function `connect` is called. But the `rows` gets populated only inside the `map()`. Hence, after you start listening to your `Gizmosubject`it is never reset to 0. This function is like a callback which has its own scope and is asynchronous, is not impacted by the `this.rows.length = 0;` at the beginning of the `connect` function.